# If statements not working with strings

Tags: java, string, if-statement

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class project{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        do{
            try {
                URL c = new URL("http://localhost/Upload2/c.txt");
                URL cinfo = new URL("http://localhost/Upload2/cinfo.txt");
                Scanner c2 = new Scanner(c.openStream());
                Scanner cinfo2 = new Scanner(cinfo.openStream());
                String c3 = c2.nextLine();
                String cinfo3 = cinfo2.nextLine();
                if ("commandline".compareTo(c3) == 0){
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cinfo3);
                    if ("idle".compareTo(c3) == 0){
                        System.out.println("Waiting for a command.");
                    }
                    if ("print".compareTo(c3) == 0){
                        System.out.println(cinfo3);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while(true);
    }
}
```

This is my current code. However, none of the if statements work! For example, even when the text file says "idle", nothing happened! I even tried to print the value of the text file and it worked (it said idle).

Comment: Yeah, you should really try to use proper indentation. It makes mistakes like these simple to spot. Edit: It's also kind of courteous to people on SO who have to *read* your code if you format it nicely - I expect that was why someone downvoted you earlier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first `if`: `if ("commandline"...)` encapsulates the following 2 of them inside. This means that if the first `if` evaluates to `false`, the following ones will never execute.

Comment: This question indicates the importance of properly indenting your code. +1

Comment: Yeah, I spotted this in the middle of fixing the code indentation...

Comment: Thanks (that was the problem). And sorry about the indentation.

Comment: You're welcome. Other suggestion: don't use a while(true). Give it a chance to stop if some condition is satisfied.

Comment: Accident. I tried to accept both legitimate answers (I'm new here). I re accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

This is because second and third `if` statement are nested under first one. Here's the relevant part, with fixed indentation:

```
if ("commandline".compareTo(c3) == 0){
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cinfo3);
  // here, we're still inside first if!
  if ("idle".compareTo(c3) == 0){
     System.out.println("Waiting for a command.");
  }
  if ("print".compareTo(c3) == 0){
     System.out.println(cinfo3);
  }
}
```

Hence, if `c3 != "commandline"`, this whole part is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using compareTo to compare strings? The string class has a comparable method - equals() or equalsIgnoreCase()

You should be creating your URL objects outside of the do-while loop. Every time the program loops through, it recreates the c and cinfo objects, meaning that it is only ever looking at the first line of each file.

Also, as others have stated, the second two if statements are never going to be executed as they are encapsulated in the first if statement.